# Solve $x^2(1-x) = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, problem-solving, octave

I have a problem $x^2(1-x) = 1$

This can be simplified ( I think ) to $-x^3 + x^2 - 1 = 0$

Google shows that there is 1 solution for this in its graph.

I am not sure how to get to that solution though?  I need to get $x$ on one side of the equation.  It doesn't seem to fit the quadratic format, but I may be wrong.

Help me remember my algebra :p

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the cubic formula

Comment: Type the following into wolframaplha and you can see the exact and numeric roots: Solve[x^2(1-x) == 1, x]. Also, to do it by hand, you can follow one of the methods here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function. Let us know if this helps. - A

Comment: There is only one real solution, there are two complex solutions. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E2%281%E2%88%92x%29%3D1

Comment: Thanks.  I am using this equation programatically to simulate a slinky falling.  I believe the cubic formula is what I need.  I'll update back here upon success : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in the numerical value of the real solution, the iteration $x\leftarrow-1/\sqrt{1-x}$ with initial value $x=0$ will also give you the solution $x=-0.75487766624669$ to 14 decimal places after 23 iterations.

Answer (score -1):

Answer was in the comments.  I used the Cubic Formula to solve.

Additionally, I was using Octave to do simulations that utilize this equation.

Octave actually has a roots function to find the roots of a given polynomial

example:

```
octave:1> c = [1,1,0,-1]
c =

   1   1   0  -1

octave:2> roots(c)
ans =

  -0.87744 + 0.74486i
  -0.87744 - 0.74486i
   0.75488 + 0.00000i
```